# I cannot find all things in sub modules of omnet++5

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

From where I could find router, client, server in omnet++5? I have just two things in my sub-modules iBidirectional and iUnidirectional, i am a beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

you should install INET Simulation model...
Click Help --> Install Simulation Model --> INET

And this is INET tutorial for beginner: http://www.slideshare.net/fayruzrahma/inet-for-starters